# How to send invoice and receipt of subscription plan to the customer email via stripe API with php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have stripe product with 2 days free trial and after trial ends, I want to send invoice to customer email. And after payment successful, want to send receipt to the customer email.

How to send invoice and receipt to the customer email via stripe API with php?